# Fallout Tactics character stuck

Tags: fallout-tactics

I'm currently on the first level of Fallout Tactics.  I generally move my characters in sneak mode where possible.  I've also got turn based set to individual.  When my characters move over some sort of obstacle, e.g. a barrel, crate or tank trap, they finish their move there even though they have action points remaining.  When the character is stuck you can click on them to move them and an animation plays as though they're going to move but they don't actually move.  While stuck the character can perform other actions such as changing pose.  The only way to get a character unstuck is to end their turn.  I've just downloaded Fallout Tactics from GOG so hopefully I have the latest version (file date is 28/11/2008).  Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there's a setting in the game that limits the number of moves you can make so you always have action points available to fire.  I think pressing either Ctrl or Shift on the keyboard toggles between the modes.  I just happened to be near an obstacle when I stopped moving so that was a red herring.